# Copy and paste from OSX to Ubuntu via Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, macosx

I am running a:

MBP on 10.14.1 with Virtualbox 5.2.22 installed running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

On the guest I went through and updated everything with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Next I installed Vbox extensions and then installed Virtualbox guest additions using this command. 
`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`

I rebooted the guest between each step.
Lastly, I enabled **Bidirectional** *Drag and Drop* and *Shared Clipboard* under Machines and rebooted. 
After all this I checked if I was able to copy and paste, to my disappointment I still was not able to.

Am I missing anything or does this feature just not work for this setup?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried dragging and dropping? Which direction do you copy/paste; from Ubuntu to MacOS? Or reverse? Do you use right-click - copy / right-click - paste, or keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @FloT I have tried both directions for both drag and drop and copy and paste. I have tried right clicking copy and then going to terminal and clicking paste from the drop down menu. I thought maybe to get around the problem for the time being I could make a shared folder and just save the stuff I need to copy and paste in there to access them easier.

Comment: The shared folder is a work around for sure, but less handy than the shared clipboard... One other thing, did you just install VBox? Should you restart to allow the system taking your settings into account?

Comment: @FloT Restart the virtual machine or restart the host? I restarted the virtual machine countless times through all my different tests but haven't restarted virtual box or my host. Maybe I will try that now.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant VBox. And if it has no effect, I'd consider restarting the host machine as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that those commands have installed the extension pack and guest additions as you think. I've always installed guest addition from within the guest.

Comment: @FloT I just tried restarting VBox and then copy and pasting via click and copy as well as via keyboard shortcuts. On top of that I tried drag and drop from both directions. I also restarted my host and then tried again but still no luck.

Comment: @Arronical The commands listed in the question I completed all on the guest Ubuntu's terminal and then from the VBox menu bar Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image to complete the install.